# Converting Safe json into 'regular' snippet

Tags: php, json

I am testing some of my pixel fires and I have the following issue. I have a page requesting information:

```
<?
$pixel = file_get_contents("http://127.0.0.1/api/v1/pixel/preq/pixel/10102.json");
echo $pixel;
```

Which returns:

```
{"code":200,"data":"<script>\r\nalert(\"Cool JS Pixel\");\r\n<\/script>"}
```

However, I have two problems, the first of which is the 'safe' `\r\n` and escaped `/` as well as if I attempt to decode the string:

```
<?
$pixel = file_get_contents("http://127.0.0.1/api/v1/pixel/preq/pixel/10102.json");
echo json_decode($pixel);
```

I get the following error:

```
Catchable fatal error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string in plugins\plg_pixelwise\test.php on line 3
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`json_decode` returns an object, or an array if you give the optional second argument `true`. You can't echo objects if they don't provide a __toString method, only strings or numbers (you can echo arrays, but they just print "Array").

Try:

```
var_dump(json_decode($pixel));
```

Comment: Well now I feel silly, that worked great. Thank you.